# AZURE AD B2C - Custom Application Authorization

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is AZURE AD B2C designed for custom application authorization? In other words, is one able to assign the authenticated users specific application role permissions in a web application?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for the User App role and permissions feature with B2C? if not please let us know your requirement/Scenario you are looking for

Comment: Hi Raghavendra, the scenario is as follows: I need to allow users to logon to my application using Azure B2C using their social logins. The default user access should be guest. However, there are some select users whom I want to give specific application course permissions (i.e. via roles) and can also give more granular access via policies.

Comment: You could use Azure AD Custom Policies, which allow you to call a REST API during authentication. This can be used to pass the ObjectId of the user to your API, and return the roles to Azure AD B2C. B2C can then issue the roles as a claim into the token. Please refer the document on how to use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange) in Custom Policy

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C does not support custom role, but this limitation can be circumvent by using claims.

Comment: Rajdeep, thanks for your response. How does one associate or persist the custom claim given that the authenticated users are not stored on the application's database?

Comment: .net core version 4.7.2

Comment: ok, then on successful login, you can use graph api to fetch custom claim and put it inside the token (I guess jwt token)

Comment: OK, let my explore the graph api option. Thanks for your input Rajdeep